# Querying Timestamp with Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I've been facing some problems with querying Timestamps in Android. I'm using the following code

```
final java.util.Date dater = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

final Timestamp date = new Timestamp(dater);

db.collection("Subscriptions").whereEqualTo("VendorUID", user.getUid()).whereLessThan("LastDelivered", date)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Inside");
.
.
.
```

This query doesn't work for me. The date in the Firestore Database is 1 May and stored in Timestamp format.

I'm able to see the Log "Inside" when I remove the "LastDelivered" part of query.
How should I go about this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of a document that's you'd expect to be returned by this query.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo